# Android: Sending image URI from webview website to app

Tags: javascript, android, webview, uri

I'm trying to send an image URI from a Website canvas to application with Javascript.
In the Website I'm using the following function that relies on the html2canvas plugin:

```
$("div.imagecapture").click(function()
{
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('paper_trolley_center'), 
    {
                onrendered: function(canvas) 
        {
            var strDataURI = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
            console.log('La imagen: '+strDataURI);
            jsNativeInterface.metodoDemo1(strDataURI);
                }
             });
});
```

The console.log outputs the URI, but the application is receiving a null value:

```
    public void metodoDemo1(Uri imageUri) 
    {  
             Log.d(TAG, "IMAGEURI: "+imageUri);
             senddatatodevice(imageUri);
    }
```

The data transmission between the app and the webview website works fine as I can receive a string (changing the casting of metodoDemo1) and do the log correctly...
What can it be?

Comment: Can you help me please to understand your code, 
What is senddatatodevice ? and did you used loadUrl or evaluateJavascript ?
I really need that code, i'm trying to get screenshot of a captcha in webview, i've been trying for a month without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing it as `String`. `Uri` in `JavaScript` is something else as in `Android`.

```
public void metodoDemo1(String imageUri)
```

Comment: Indeed, I only used basic types such as String/Boolean/Integers

Comment: When I try to handle the URI I get this error:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAP... (Here comes all the URI)

Comment: This means your URI is not pointing to data, but it contains the data in itself (base64 encoded)

Comment: Exactly, it is not pointing to any data, is the data itself coming from the Web. How can I handle it?